# How to set cookie without encryption [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, encryption

I have one problem. I know how to set cookie in a controller:

```
cookies.signed["@cookieName"] = {
    value: @cookieValue,
    :expires => 1.year.from_now
}
```

But there is a problem. This is going to encrypt cookie. But my cookie is already encrypted, so I need to set exact value that I get from another method. Long, encrypted key.

Is it possible?

Comment: @HolgerJust Did you even read my question? I am not asking about expire.

Comment: And have you read the accepted answer of the linked question?

Comment: @HolgerJust Yes, I have. Is there answer to my question? Anyway the question is not the same.

Comment: I found out that my cookies are setting just like I need to except one thing. They change characters like tilda (~) to %7E. Is it ok or do I have an option to set it like it should be (it means with tilda etc.)?

Comment: I think I cant accept my answer because of @HolgerJust (thanks for that), but this is the right answer on question How to set cookie without encryption (ad: not exactly without encryption, if you want to set cookie with exactly same value): response["set-cookie"]="cookieName:blabla=#{valueOfCookie}"  If you need to make long string from paragraph, then user " long string with escape characters".split.join